# R character hash function

Tags: r, hash, text-classification

Ok this question is related to this one: [Feature hashing in R for Text classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26446728/feature-hashing-in-r-for-text-classification). What's a reasonable way to hash an `character vector` to an `integer` in R?
My current code just take the last hex chars and convert then, but it doesn't seems to extract features very well (i've tested it in a very simple classification problem):

```
library(digest)
bad_hash = function(word, N){
    strtoi(substr(digest(word), 28, 32), 16L) %% (N + 1)
}

bad_hash('this is sparta', 100)
# 97
```

Thanks!

Comment: Google "hash function for string", for [example](http://research.cs.vt.edu/AVresearch/hashing/strings.php)

Comment: I know, but this example is weird to implement in R, and it would be too slow to apply.